# How to update php variable with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms

Not sure of I should be looking for, here is what I am needing to accomplish.

I'm creating a stock trading simulation game.

I have created a php function that appears in my page code as (where AAPL is the symbol):

```
<?php displayQuoteDetailed(AAPL); ?>
```

I would like to have a text input and a submit button located in my sidebar to change the symbol on the php function to display quote without the entire page reloading.

From my google searching, it seems this could be accomplished by using javascript but I have been unable to locate exactly how to change the symbol used in the php function and how to get the stock quote to update without page reload.  Thanks for any help!  I'm learning as I go.

Comment: Google "Ajax". That's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX (XMLHttpRequest unless using IE). If you're new and want your app to work across most web browsers use jQuery:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```